# How can i split data from string in php?

Tags: php, string

I have a string in PHP like the following

```
$data = "ID=53KEY=23";
```

and i want to assign value from this string to following variables

```
$id = 53;
$key = 23;
```

How can i do this in php, please help?

Comment: That might be difficult if there nothing separating the value from the next key (e.g. `53KEY`). Are the values always numeric and the keys always alphabetic?

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers mates. It really helped, I am going to try everything...

Answer (score 3):

This function will work for more generic key/value inputs, not just ID/KEY

```
$input = "ID=53KEY=23";

$res = preg_split("/([[:upper:]]+)=([[:digit:]]+)/", $input, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($res) ; $i += 2)
{
    $res[$i] = strtolower($res[$i]);
    $$res[$i] = $res[$i+1];
}

//$id = 53
//$key = 23
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$data = "ID=53KEY=23"; 

preg_match("/id=(?<id>\d+)&?key=(?<key>\d+)/i",$data,$array); 
$id = $array["id"]; // 53
$key = $array["key"]; //23
print("id = $id, key = $key\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

For a more generic solution:

```
$data = "ID=53KEY=23AGE=318";
$array = array();
if(preg_match_all("/([A-Z]+)=(\d+)/", $data, $matches)) {
    $array = array_change_key_case(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
}

echo "ID: " . $array['id'] . ", KEY: " . $array['key'] . ", AGE: " . $array['age'];
```